# How many different menus can the customer order?

Tags: combinatorics

There is a restaurant that has 5 different options in the menu. A customer can only choose 3 of them for a meal. So how many different orders can the customer give for 3 meals?

Comment: Does the customer have to choose $3$ or can he choose say $1,2,$ or $3$ ?

Comment: @coffeemath he can choose 1,2 or 3.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a 
real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much 
progress. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? How far could you get? 
Where are you stuck? This question will likely be closed if you don't add more 
context. Please respond by **editing the question body**. 
Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

For a single meal he can choose one option in $5$ ways, two options in $\binom{5}{2}$ ways, and three options in $\binom{5}{3}$ ways. Add these to get number of ways to choose a single meal.

If he is to order three meals, he can do it in the cube of the previous total.

Here the "binomial coefficient" $\binom{n}{k}$ is the number of $k$ element subsets of an $n$ element set. It can be calculated as $n!/(k!(n-k)!)$ where $b!$ is "b factorial" and is the product of the integers from $1$ to $b.$